# Open file with a specific path on Android application C#, Maui

Tags: c#, android, excel, path, maui

Everyone

I need to load an Excel file which has a specific location on my phone. The location is from the documents folder. Below is the code I have tried so far, but the error that is being thrown points to the application searching for the file on my PC. I am using USB debugging to test the application on my phone while writing the code. Please help me in loading the file from phone which has been created and saved on my phone. I am using GemBox.spreadsheets to load, read, write, and save the excel file.

```
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Environment;

namespace Test4
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        static MainPage()
        {
            SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "test3.xlsx");
            ExcelFile work_book = ExcelFile.Load(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `file from phone which has been created and saved on my phone.` Ok. But who did all that? Your app?

Comment: Please tell full path of that file.

Comment: So I have created the file myself. The path would be "/Internal storage/Documents/test3.xlsx"

Comment: That is a non existent path for an Android device. Your Android app can never have used that path to create the file. Myself? How?

Comment: My application didn't create that path. Before running my application I created that file on my phone using excel on my phone. With my application I want to search for that file and load/open it.

Comment: Ok. Your app did not create that file. Then it cannot search for it directly. Or if it knows full path (not that impossible path you mentioned) it could 'see' that the file existed (using File:exists()) but it could also 'see' that it could not read the file using File:canRead(). Apps have no access to other apps files now adays.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android Environment to get the documents folder: Instead of using Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), you can use Android-specific code to get the documents folder on your phone.

```
var documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
```

var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "test3.xlsx");

Comment: It gives an error: 'Android' does not contain a definition for 'OS'.